# Appium - Scroll to a button not working

Tags: javascript, android, testing, automated-tests, appium

So I've been trying to scroll down to a Submit button on my `Android` app(made using `Kony Visualiser`) but for some reason nothing seems to be working. So far I've tried:

- `touchPerform`, `touchAction`, `findElementbyAndroidUiAutomator`, changing `longPress` to `press`, adding a `wait` action, reversing the x and y figures, changing the values and several other suggestions I've seen online.

Appium version: v1.8.0

My current `JavaScript` code works when I am scrolling through other elements (segment) and only doesn't work in this specific situation where I'm trying to scroll down a scrollable flexbox.

Here is a snippet of my current code:

```js
.touchPerform([
  { action: 'longPress', options: { x: 50, y: 1800 }},
  { action: 'moveTo', options: { x: 50, y: 0 }},
  { action: 'release' }
])
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes still use driver.swipe even tough it's getting deprecated.

`driver.swipe(width, startPoint, width, endPoint, duration);`

The better way would be:

`TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.press(startX, startY).moveTo((endX - startX), (endY-startY)).release().perform();`

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. Appium wont let me run my test with deprecated functions and I've tried using TouchAction before but it wouldn't work either. Strangely enough, TouchPerform works on one test case but not any of the rest even though they are all either the same/almost the same.

Comment: Hi sorry I just managed to get it to work! I ended up using a deviceKeyEvent(93) which solved the problem quite well. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Reina: Make sure you keep flex-scroll container scroll direction set to vertical/both, layout-type vertical. Thanks!

Comment: It's already been set to that but I ended up using a deviceKeyEvent(93) which solved the problem quite well. Thanks for the help anyway!